# BPF Filter TCP Connections

Tags: tcp, filter, wireshark, bpf

I'm trying to capture from a pcap file connections that starts correctly (with 3-way protocol: syn,syn-ack,ack) and ends correctly.

```
To capture connections that starts correctly I use the following filter:
(tcp.flags.syn == 1) || (tcp.flags.syn==1 && tcp.flags.ack==1)
```

I don't filter just by ack's because it will filter every single package that contains an ack and isn't useful to me. So I use: SYN or SYN-ACK flags to filter.That's only for starting connections so, **how I should filter packages to get also ending packages?**

```
I'm using something like this: (tcp.flags.fin==1) || (tcp.flags.fin==1 && tcp.flags.ack==1)
```

I don't feel that's correct because I don't know exactly how every connection ends, **that depends on implementation? or is always the same?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is always the same for TCP connection, save for abnormal situations when a peer reset the connection (RST flag). Also, in wireshark you have convenient option: if you right-click a packet a choose "follow TCP stream" it will display only packets belonging to that connection, so you can see how it starts and ends...